# How to loop through array values using ngFor and interpolation in Angular

Tags: angular, ngfor

The `Employee` object in my Angular app contains an array of `Skill` objects, like below:

```
export interface IEmployee {
    id: number;
    fullName: string;
    skills: ISkill[];
}
```

Here is my `Skill interface`:

```
export interface ISkill {
    skillName: string;
    experienceInYears: number;
    proficiency: string;
}
```

I am able to use interpolation to display employee details like so:

```
{{employee.fullName}}
```

Now, I am trying to display the employee's skill.

Below, I am able to display the first `skill`:

```
{{employee.skills[0]?.skillName}}
```

But I want to display all of the skills associated with that employee, not just the first one.

I think the solution might have something to do with `ngFor`, but not sure exactly how to implement it.

Can someone please tell me how I can loop through the skills array to display all skillName's in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `ngFor` for the skills of the particular employee.

Something like this should do the trick.

```
<div *ngFor="let skill of employee.skills">
  {{skill.skillName}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over your skills array like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let skill of employee.skills" >
   <span>{{skill.skillName}}</span>
   <span>{{skill.experienceInYears}}</span>
   <span>{{skill.proficiency}}</span>

</div>
```

You can find more info [here](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngFor="let skill of employee.skills">
    <div>{{ skill.skillName }}</div>
    <div>{{ skill.proficiency }}</div>
    <div>{{ skill.experienceInYears }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the docu for more informations: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

```
<div *ngFor="let skill of employee.skills">
      {{ skill.name }}
    </div>
```